# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I am getting the error "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements." while running my app using the provisional profiles created using particular id(clients id). I have tried with another ids(our development ids) then it is working fine. I don't know whats wrong with me...Can any body suggest me a solution?

I found many solutions regarding the .plist file changes and bundle identifier name changes etc ..But I have tried the same project using alternative id,but it is working.So i think the problem will not be with the project.
Thanks in advance

Comment: the profile you are using does not have the device registered..

Answer (score 4):

This quite often happens when updating XCode to a new version. If you are sure that your device has the correct provisioning profile and that the code signing section of your app has the correct information then sometimes what works is to restart XCode so that it can clear any derived data from your project that conflicts. Worked for me

Comment: Indeed, this just happened to me after upgrading to 7.1. Even when I created a new app, this error would pop-up. A simple restart fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

possible reason as you are trying to profile iOS App where the iOS device is not included in Your iOS provisioning profile and please follow this link [TROUBLESHOOTING GUIDE CODE SIGNING ENTITLEMENTS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_GUIDE-CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS)

Comment: No. I have cross checked that many times. I also checked with different devices

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project settings and make sure the provisioning profile is one that matches your current application identifier

Then go to the target settings and make sure that it is the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to bet that the provisioning profile you are using does not have your cert/keychain private key pair associated with it. I would suggest posting what Keychain Access looks like for the cert tied to the provisioning profile you're trying to sign the code to.

Answer (score 0):

I got you!!

I believe you haven't installed the .cer.
Login to your member centre --> certificates --> Development.

Now download and install certificates of type "**iOS Development**"

Now come back to your xcode. Select buil settings as usual ans Vioala... :)